# WPF Bind ListBoxItem to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, data-binding

I need to bind the ListBoxItem and DataGrid in the following way:
A user doubleclicks on the ListBoxItem and the sql query is performed and the retrieved data is shown on the DataGrid.
Here's what I have:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GridStatistics" Margin="0,144,0,0" />
<ListBox x:Name="LstStat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="129" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="330" FontSize="16"
          ItemsSource="{Binding StatisticsQueries}" Cursor="Arrow" PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="LstStat_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="LstStat_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp" MouseDoubleClick="LstStat_MouseDoubleClick">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" FontWeight="Medium" FontSize="18" FontFamily="HelveticaNeueCyr"/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <ListBox.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu>
               <MenuItem Header="Show" Click="MenuItem_OnClick" />
          </ContextMenu>
      </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

And my c# code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Query> StatisticsQueries {get{...}}

private void LstStat_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (LstStat.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
    var item = LstStat.SelectedItem as Query;
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(DatabaseModel.ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        if (item != null)
            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(item.Text, connection))
            {
                var dt = new DataTable();
                var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                GridStatistics.DataContext = dt;
            }
        connection.Close();
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

And the class Query `public class Query : INotifyPropertyChanged` has all the properties that are used in the code, so no mistakes there.

Although the data is retrieved correctly, the DataGrid doesn't react at all. Maybe there are some mistakes in binding or setting DataContext.

Could you please help me to correctly bind the ListBoxItem DoubleMouseClick and DataGrid DataContext? Should I create a separate class for that?

Comment: change to GridStatistics.ItemsSource= dt;

Comment: @RezaArabQaeni unfortunately, there's no property DataSource :(

Comment: Right, I edit that to ItemsSource.

Comment: @RezaArabQaeni `ItemsSource` takes `IEnumerable`, but `dt` is `DataTable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue doing this:

1) Adding this:

```
public DataTable StatisticsDataTable { get; private set; }
```

2) Then changing my method part here:

```
                StatisticsDataTable = dt;
                GridStatistics.DataContext = StatisticsDataTable;
```

3) The XAML binding became the following:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

Thanks everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try it :

using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(item.Text, connection))
{
     .
     .
     GridStatistics.ItemsSource =  dt.DefaultView;

}
```